# Redux-Saga How do I cancle exsisting calls of the same type?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, redux-saga

I want to make it so all calls that are created fron said function/constant are canceled when starting a new one so whne I export with take latest it only returns one  (the newest result=

```
function* getLatestNews(data) {

  try {      
       //Get all other getLatestNews created by user and cancel them before starting this one 
       //yield takeall("NEWS_CALL") then delete...?
       const { news} = yield call(() => GetNewsForData(actions.getNews(data)).then(response => response));

      if (data) {
        yield put(actions.setNewsSuccess(data));
      } else {
        yield put(actions.setNewsFailed());
      }
  }...

}
```